# Why does Win32 API LoadLibrary fail when loading a dll linked to libmonosgen-2.0?

Tags: winapi, mono, mono-embedding

I have made a win C/C++ dll that embeds the Mono Clr - it's only a couple of calls at the moment. I have linked to the calls using the .def file (and some tweaking) to generate a .lib.
These calls are in a file called libmonosgen-2.0.dll. No error is shown that says the libmonosgen-2.0.dll cannot be found.

When I try to load my .dll with a C/C++ test app using the LoadLibrary Win32 API, it fails with code 193/C1 - bad image. When I remove the link to the libmonosgen-2.0.dll, it loads fine again.

I have looked at my dll with Dependency-Walker but no odd dependencies are there (all system32 stuff).

I really have no clue why this problem exists.

PS: I cannot put the Mono embedding code in an .exe because I am building a plugin - it has to be a .dll.

EDIT:
I had 32-bit and 64 bit images mixed. The mono install is 32-bit (3.2.3 at least).

Comment: It is a pretty specific error code.  Look at the file header with dumpbin.exe /headers.  Wrong machine or subsystem version are 99% of the reasons.

Comment: It might also be worth using Process Monitor to double-check that the DLL being loaded is the one you were expecting.

Comment: Ah, so it could be as simple as trying to use a 32-bit dll in my 64 bit project? I've tried to profile with DependencyWalker but my .exe turned into ConHost.Exe and I lost track of what what doing what where to whom...

Comment: Using dumpbin: I can see libmonosgen-2.0 is indeed 32 bit (verified with dumpbin). Recompiled everything to 32 bit, still same error. I can see two RESERVED - UNKNOWN flags in the sections (.text .data etc.) - could that be causing the problem? My own .dll and test app .exe do not have these RESERVED flags...

Comment: Just checked: Did a LoadLibrary on libmonosgen-2.0 directly and that works (return value is non-null). Soooo...

Comment: Oops no. I had my images confused. The issue was a mixup of 32- and 64-bit. Works now.